# InstanceAlreadyExistsExceplion while using ApplicationContext Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm new to Spring Framework and I trying to understand how Spring Beans work, but I get BeanCreationException and InstanceAlreadyExistsException every time when I use ApplicationConfig class.

This is my configuration-annotated class:

```
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class ApplicationConfig {
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        DataSourceBuilder dataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create();
        dataSource.username("root");
        dataSource.password("password");
        dataSource.url("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schedule");
        dataSource.driverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        return dataSource.build();
    }
}
```

And this is my DAO class:

```
package com.example.demo;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class UserDAO {
    private DataSource dataSource;

    private UserDAO(DataSource dataSource) { // (1)
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }
}
```

If I create a new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext object in my MainApplication class

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
        ApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(ApplicationConfig.class);
    }

}
```

I get this error code:

```
**Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException**
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:119)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springApplicationAdminRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/admin/SpringApplicationAdminJmxAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.springframework.boot:type=Admin,name=SpringApplication
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:93)
    at com.example.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:13)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: **javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.springframework.boot:type=Admin,name=SpringApplication**
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:436)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1862)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:957)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:892)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:317)
    at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:523)
    at org.springframework.boot.admin.SpringApplicationAdminMXBeanRegistrar.afterPropertiesSet(SpringApplicationAdminMXBeanRegistrar.java:129)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800)
    ... 14 more
```

I've been trying to fix this since yesterday morning and I've tried a million approaches. I hope I will find the answer here!

Comment: Oh, I noticed, that i didn't annotate DAO class with @Component in the example! But that is not the reason of my problem

Comment: You don't need to use AnnotationConfigApplicationContext. Spring boot will load all the configuration when you run the application SpringApplication.run

Comment: @ChetanAhirrao wow. But if i don't use AnnotationConfigApplicationContext how can I access the created UserDAO instance? For example, if I need to use some UserDAO object methods.